# Different file_get_contents() result on different hostings

Tags: php, xml

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $string = file_get_contents($url); 
    var_dump($string);
?>
```

There are different results from `file_get_contents()` for two different hosts.

Is there any server configuration that I have to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header' => implode("\r\n", array(
            'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1',
    'Accept-Encoding: ',
    )),
)));

$string= file_get_contents($url, null, $context);    
var_dump($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks gzipped. I suggest using a more intelligent utility than file_get_contents, like cURL.

Comment: I tried with cURL, got this error `Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found`. @nc's is correct, thanks anyway.